# sqlite3 search database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My database originally a sql file, converted to sqlite file, data.sqlite. 
Data base, is a book with chapter and verse numbers. The table is

```
`#INSERT INTO `booktext` (`index`, `chapter`, `verse`, `text`) VALUES`
def read_from_db():
    table='booktext'
    chapter =100
    sql = '''SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE chapter= {1}'''.format(table,chapter)
    c.execute(sql)
    data = c.fetchall()
    print (data) #returns emty list
return data
```

Returns an empty list. However, when I do not select chapter, for fetching all the verses in the chapter, but instead write:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM 'booktext'")
```

All chapter and verse numbers with text appears, as expected. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Maybe in the proces when I converted the sql file to data.sqlite, the data table, got changed. Is there a way to see what is the current data table?

In my original sql file, the guide for using the database is;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `booktext`;
CREATE TABLE `booktext` ('index` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`chapter` int(3) NOT NULL default '0',
`verse` int(3) NOT NULL default '0',
`text` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`index`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Table name cannot be parametrized. You need to use string concatenation or interpolation (both potentially dangerous - SQL Injection).

Comment: Yea, I did that; like this;  c.execute("SELECT * FROM 'booktext' WHERE chapter = '100' '")
But still the same problem.